# Formula is satisfiable iff its existential closure is satisfiable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How can I prove this statement:

> A formula is satisfiable iff its existential closure is satisfiable(the formula has $n$ free variables which are $x_1,\dots,x_n$).

A formula $\varphi$ is satisfiable if and only if  there is a structure  $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \vDash \varphi$ .
I applied this definition to $\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right),$

and say there is a tuple $\vec{a}=(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})$ in M satisfying $\varphi$ in $\mathcal{M}$ s.t.

$ \mathcal{M} \vDash \varphi\left(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}\right)$

And applying this definition to $\exists x_{1}, \ldots x_{n}  \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right),$

$ \mathcal{M} \vDash \exists x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}  \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)$

and after I say these, which steps should I follow?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

Recall a formula $\psi$ is satisfiable if and only if in some model $\mathfrak{M} \models \psi$. This is the definition of satisfiability.

So applying this definition to $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, we see this is asking for

- a model $\mathfrak{M}$
- elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathfrak{M}$
- $\mathfrak{M} \models \varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.

And applying this definition to $\exists x_1, \ldots x_n . \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, we see we want

- a model $\mathfrak{M}$
- $\mathfrak{M} \models \exists x_1, \ldots, x_n . \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$

Do you see why these are equivalent conditions? It might be worth reviewing the definition of $\mathfrak{M} \models \exists z . \psi(z)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^